# ¿Por qué phpmyadmin no me deja usar camellcase en mis tablas?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Estoy en `phpmyadmin` y observo que no me deja crear tablas con nombres camellcase, la verdad no sé por que pase esto.

¿alguien sabrá el motivo?

Uso como servidor `XAMPP` Control Panel v3.24

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: XAMPP es irrelevante a la pregunta.. mysql funciona por si mismo sin XAMPP.. estas trabajando en windows no? esta pregunta en ingles es tu respuesta: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4360770/mysql-cant-give-tables-a-name-in-upper-camel-case-pascal-case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`phpMyAdmin` no es quien modifica el nombre de las tablas, sino `MySQL`

- [Identifier Case Sensitivity](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html)

> In MySQL, databases correspond to directories within the data directory. Each table within a database corresponds to at least one file within the database directory (and possibly more, depending on the storage engine). Triggers also correspond to files. Consequently, the case sensitivity of the underlying operating system plays a part in the case sensitivity of database, table, and trigger names. This means such names are not case-sensitive in Windows, but are case-sensitive in most varieties of Unix. One notable exception is macOS, which is Unix-based but uses a default file system type (HFS+) that is not case-sensitive. However, macOS also supports UFS volumes, which are case-sensitive just as on any Unix.
>
> ---
>
> En MySQL, las bases de datos corresponden a directorios dentro del directorio de datos. **Cada tabla dentro de una base de datos corresponde a al menos un archivo dentro del directorio de la base de datos** (y posiblemente más, dependiendo del motor de almacenamiento). Los disparadores también corresponden a archivos. **En consecuencia, la distinción entre mayúsculas y minúsculas del sistema operativo subyacente juega un papel en la distinción entre mayúsculas y minúsculas de los nombres de base de datos, tablas y activadores**. Esto significa que dichos nombres no distinguen entre mayúsculas y minúsculas en Windows, pero sí en la mayoría de las variedades de Unix. Una excepción notable es macOS, que está basado en Unix pero utiliza un tipo de sistema de archivos predeterminado (HFS +) que no distingue entre mayúsculas y minúsculas. Sin embargo, macOS también admite volúmenes UFS, que distinguen entre mayúsculas y minúsculas al igual que en cualquier Unix.

En resumen, por cuestiones de compatibilidad entre Sistemas Operativos, es que por defecto se lleva todo a minúsculas.

Si realmente estas interesado en mantener el "camelcase", podes lograrlo modificando el valor de la variable [`lower_case_table_names`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_lower_case_table_names):

> If set to 0, table names are stored as specified and comparisons are case-sensitive. If set to 1, table names are stored in lowercase on disk and comparisons are not case-sensitive. If set to 2, table names are stored as given but compared in lowercase. This option also applies to database names and table aliases.
>
> ---
>
> Si se establece en `0`, los nombres de las tablas se almacenan como se especifica y las comparaciones distinguen entre mayúsculas y minúsculas. Si se establece en `1`, los nombres de las tablas se almacenan en minúsculas en el disco y las comparaciones no distinguen entre mayúsculas y minúsculas. Si se establece en `2`, los nombres de las tablas se almacenan como se dan pero se comparan en minúsculas. Esta opción también se aplica a los nombres de bases de datos y alias de tablas.